# Is there a way to take user input to define array size in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I was trying to take user input `n` (`cin >> n`) and using that `n` to define the array size (`arr[n]`). It works on other compilers, but on Visual Studio it is not working, so trying to find the root of the problem and is there a way around?

This is a hackerrank problem, my submission was successfully accepted, I've tried on multiple online and offline compilers, my code works, it's only on Visual Studio that I'm facing the issue.

```
int n;
cin >> n;

int arr[n]; //this line has the error
```

The error I'm getting is:

> Error (active) E0028   expression must have a constant value   Project2    D:\Code\C++\source\Project2\Source.cpp  in line 9

Comment: Yes, use `std::vector` instead of an array.

Comment: *"It works on other compilers but on visual studio it is not working"* You have it backwards. You aren't allowed to do that in C++, but a few compilers support it as an extension of the language. Visual Studio is not one of those few compilers that allows it.

Comment: If using `std::vector`: As you know size in advance, do it this way: `std::vector<int> arr; arr.reserve(n);` – this way you'll prevent unnecessary re-allocations.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard

Comment: Use `std::array` if size is known at compile time. Use `std::vector` if size is only known at run time. Don't use C-style arrays *at all* if you value your sanity. And *definitely* don't use C-style Variable Length Arrays as they are not part of standard C++ (only supported by *some* compilers as a - non portable - language *extension*). What you want here is [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), period.

Comment: For GCC or clang: `-std=c++17` will disable such extensions like VLA.

Comment: @Aconcagua and if you don't do that (which I agree is the *right* thing to do), `-Wvla -Werror` can help in this specific case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Dynamic 1D array in the following way for this purpose.

```
int count;
cin >> count;
int *a = new int[count];
```

Comment: You can, but you shouldn't. Use an `std::vector`.